# PathFindExtensionW always return "." instead of full extension

Tags: c, winapi

I have the following path and filename

```
"C:\\Users\\msi\\Desktop\\read-file\\read-file.sdf"
```

With `PathFindExtensionW` function, the expected return string is `".sdf"` but it returns `"."` instead!

This is my `code` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

#define FILENAME        "C:\\Users\\msi\\Desktop\\read-file\\read-file.sdf"                 // current file-path
#define MAX_FILE_EXT    90                                      // maximum file-extension length
#define ERR_MSG         "Cannot open the specific file!\n"  // error message if couldn't open the file

#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")                             // add this static library for using of PathFindExtension

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW data = {0};
    HANDLE fh = 0;

    if((FindFirstFile(TEXT(FILENAME), &data)) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WCHAR file_ext[MAX_FILE_EXT] = {0};
        lstrcpy(file_ext, PathFindExtension(TEXT(FILENAME)));

        printf("File-extension is : '%s'\n", PathFindExtensionW(TEXT(FILENAME)));
    }
    else
        printf(ERR_MSG);

    return 0;
}
```

By the way, I used `wchar_t*`, so I had to call `PathFindExtensionW`. Although I called `PathFindExtension`, it returned the same result.

Comment: Use `%ls` instead of `%s`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is Unicode (which is recommended), you don't really need the `TEXT` macro which only adds `L` prefix when `UNICODE` is defined. You can do that yourself:

```
const wchar_t *wstr = L"this is a wide char string"; //or const WCHAR*, same thing
```

`PathFindExtension` is a macro, which is defined as `PathFindExtensionW` when `UNICODE` is defined.

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define PathFindExtension  PathFindExtensionW
#else
#define PathFindExtension  PathFindExtensionA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

So you can just write `PathFindExtension`

`lstrcpy` copy is fine, but it is a Windows specific function. New programs can use wide char version of string functions, `wcscpy` instead of `strcpy`, `wcslen` instead of `strlen`, `wcsxxx` instead of `strxxx` ...

`"C:\\Users\\msi\\Desktop"` should not be hard-coded. Use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` to find the desktop path, example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <KnownFolders.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")  

int main(void)
{
    wchar_t desktop[MAX_PATH];

    //get desktop path:
    wchar_t *ptr;
    SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &ptr);
    wcscpy_s(desktop, _countof(desktop), ptr);
    CoTaskMemFree(ptr);

    //make filename from desktop path:
    wchar_t filename[MAX_PATH];
    swprintf(filename, _countof(filename), L"%s\\read-file\\read-file.sdf", desktop);

    if (PathFileExists(filename))
        wprintf(L"File-extension is : '%s'\n", PathFindExtension(filename));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: very nice answer. its complete

Answer (score 1):

When we are intended to use the `printf` to print out a `wide-string`, we should use `"%ls"` format specifier, not `"%s"`.

However, using `"%s"` with `wprintf` is perfectly fine.

This is the rule :

```
WCHAR *wstr = "this is wide string";
CHAR *str = "this is string";

wprintf("%s", wstr);
printf("%ls", wstr);

printf("%s", str);
```